# Downgrade Android OS from Android Pie

Tags: downgrade

One of our devices had the OS upgraded to Android Pie. How do I identify the time and date that the update occurred?  Is there a way to downgrade the OS back to the Android version from which it was upgraded?

Comment: What manufacturer?

Comment: Which device is it? You should also check out if the device supports firmware downgrade or not. Unsupported devices get bricked during this process.

Comment: thanks for very quick response, Device is Xiami Redmi MI 5 Pro @BoLawson

Comment: thanks for the help could you plz guide  me to  know  the steps  to check device supports firmware downgrade or not.. @Firelord

Comment: @reema First you need to download the device firmware image for the exact device type you use in the version you want. I don't know if Xiami provides (old) firmware images for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I identify the time and date that the update occurred?

1. Open your device's Settings app.
2. Click on "Software Update"
3. You will see a "Last Update" entry at the bottom
   e.g.  The last update was installed on xxxx x, xxxx at xx:xx PM.

> Is there a way to downgrade the OS back to the Android version from which it was upgraded?

The short answer is 'Yes.'  The long answer: This is a very complex process that is typically not encouraged by vendors or manufacturers so you won't be getting support from them.  You also run the risk of losing data, permanently losing use of your device (bricking), losing warranty, amongst other issues.  I would respectfully suggest that this may be more than you should be taking on.  You will find it very challenging and unless you find a site in your native language, you are apt to miss some small (or large) detail or nuance.

Having said that there is a very active community of users who do this sort of thing. You might want to hop over to [XDA Developers Forum for Xiaomi devices](https://www.xda-developers.com/tag/xiaomi/) and see what you dig up, but I would be very cautious about what you do and whose advice you take.

Comment: Thanks for your great help, but still m stuck with identify the time and date that update occured,because my device received another update of MIUI 10.2.2.0 |Stable that's the simple step not showing in my device.thanks again.